# Port 80 showing as filtered, ufw inactive

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

```
sudo nmap -sS 3.139.146.153

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
25/tcp   filtered smtp
80/tcp   filtered http
443/tcp  open     https
3306/tcp open     mysql
7000/tcp open     afs3-fileserver
7200/tcp open     fodms
8000/tcp open     http-alt
```

`sudo iptables -xvnL` Given Below Output

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 543021 packets, 222443266 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      14      870 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   14676  3583305 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   14676  3583305 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    6237  1145719 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1307    71072 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    7132  2366514 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 422937 packets, 410376615 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     184     9948 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    7132  2366514 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   14676  3583305 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    7132  2366514 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   14676  3583305 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

How can we open port 80?

Comment: Is it filtered at the ISP? It often is.

Comment: It is showing always in filtered STATE

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
25/tcp   filtered smtp
80/tcp   filtered http
443/tcp  open     https
3306/tcp open     mysql
7000/tcp open     afs3-fileserver
7200/tcp open     fodms
8000/tcp open     http-alt

Comment: For Clear Out Put Please Check This Link https://pastebin.com/gYQwQ6d0

Comment: sudo iptables -xvnL iptable output https://pastebin.com/t3gFP0QY

Comment: Where did you scan from?  Outside the network or inside?

Comment: I Scanned Through Putty(SSH) Login

Comment: Port 80 is not blocked via iptables. No port is blocked via iptables. You have an generic ACCEPT policy for the INPUT chain. You issue is elsewhere.

Comment: So Where I Need To Check For 80/tcp   filtered http issue?

Comment: Port 80 is not filtered, so I assume the web server is not even listening on port 80. I am assuming the web server is running on the main computer, not some docker container.

Comment: Yes Right, So What I Need To Do For Open Port 80?